# Join Two arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays and the First array name is $balances and output is below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [index] => 0
            [account_id] => 1
            [company_id] => 6
            [company_code] => ABBANK
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [index] => 6
            [account_id] => 1
            [company_id] => 147
            [company_code] => IFIC
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [index] => 11
            [account_id] => 1
            [company_id] => 293
            [company_code] => SOUTHEASTB 
        )
)
```

Second array name is $market and it's output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [company] => SOUTHEASTB
            [high] => 0
            [low] => 0

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [company] => IFIC
            [high] => 0
            [low] => 0

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [company] => ABBANK
            [high] => 0
            [low] => 0
        )
)
```

I merge this two array and getting bellow output. The 2nd array push the array value to 1st array using the code below producing a result which is not in my requirement:

```php
$result = array();
foreach ($balances as $key => $value) {
  $result[] = array_merge($value, $market[$key]);
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [index] => 0
            [company_code] => ABBANK
            [company] =>  1JANATAMF                                               
            [high] => 5.3
            [low] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [index] => 6
            [company_code] => IFIC           
            [company] => 1STPRIMFMF                                              
            [high] => 16.9
            [low] => 16.2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [index] => 11
            [company_code] => SOUTHEASTB
            [company] =>  AAMRANET                                                
            [high] => 44
            [low] => 43
        )
)
```

My challenge to check the $balances[company_code] == $market['company'] and append the 2nd array to 1st array which will produce the following result.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [index] => 0
            [account_id] => 1
            [company_id] => 6
            [company_code] => ABBANK
            [high] => 0
            [low] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [index] => 6
            [account_id] => 1
            [company_id] => 147
            [company_code] => IFIC
            [high] => 0
            [low] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [index] => 11
            [account_id] => 1
            [company_id] => 293
            [company_code] => SOUTHEASTB
            [high] => 0
            [low] => 0 
        )
)
```

But above code block is not serving my demand. Because this code block only push the second array to 1st array using merge function. I tried every other solution in my stock. Is there anyone who can give me any solution will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be solved in minimal code by using [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to re-index both arrays by the company name, the two arrays can then be merged using [`array_merge_recursive`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php):

```
$output = array_merge_recursive(array_column($balances, null, 'company_code'), 
                                array_column($market, null, 'company'));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [ABBANK] => Array
        (
            [index] => 0
            [account_id] => 1
            [company_id] => 6
            [company_code] => ABBANK
            [company] => ABBANK
            [high] => 0
            [low] => 0
        )
    [IFIC] => Array
        (
            [index] => 6
            [account_id] => 1
            [company_id] => 147
            [company_code] => IFIC
            [company] => IFIC
            [high] => 0
            [low] => 0
        )
    [SOUTHEASTB] => Array
        (
            [index] => 11
            [account_id] => 1
            [company_id] => 293
            [company_code] => SOUTHEASTB
            [company] => SOUTHEASTB
            [high] => 0
            [low] => 0
        )
)
```

If you want a numerically indexed result, just pass `$output` through [`array_values`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values).

```
$output = array_values($output);
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/k5hbO)

Answer (score 1):

I have taken two arrays '$a' and '$b', in your case it is `$balances` and `$market`, respectively. `array_push()` is the simplest thing you can do to push/append values of array '$b' to array '$a'.

```
        $a = array(array(
                    "index" => 0,
                    "account_id" => 1,
                    "company_id" => 6,
                    "company_code" => "ABBANK"
                ),
                array
                (
                    "index" => 6,
                    "account_id" => 1,
                    "company_id" => 147,
                    "company_code" => "IFIC"
                ),
                array
                (
                    "index" => 11,
                    "account_id" => 1,
                    "company_id" => 293,
                    "company_code" => "SOUTHEASTB" 
                ));
        $b = array
        (
            array
                (
                    "company" => "SOUTHEASTB",
                    "high" => 0,
                    "low" => 0,
        
                ),
                array
                (
                    "company" => "IFIC",
                    "high" => 0,
                    "low" => 0,
        
                ),
                array
                (
                    "company" => "ABBANK",
                    "high" => 0,
                    "low" => 0
                )
        );
        $result = array();
        foreach($a as $key=>$value){
            foreach($b as $key2 => $value2){
            if($value['company_code'] === $value2['company']){
                //append matched part of $b array to $a array value
                array_push($value,$value2['high'],$value2['low']);
                //append to result array
                array_push($result, $value);
            }
            }
        }
        print_r($result);
       
    
    //Output
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [index] => 0
                [account_id] => 1
                [company_id] => 6
                [company_code] => ABBANK
                [0] => 0
                [1] => 0
            )
    
        [1] => Array
            (
                [index] => 6
                [account_id] => 1
                [company_id] => 147
                [company_code] => IFIC
                [0] => 0
                [1] => 0
            )
    
        [2] => Array
            (
                [index] => 11
                [account_id] => 1
                [company_id] => 293
                [company_code] => SOUTHEASTB
                [0] => 0
                [1] => 0
            )
    
    )
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

While Nick's three-function approach is certainly attractive for its brevity, be aware that it stores the relating elements from both arrays (has redundant data in the output) and makes three iterating cycles.

A less concise alternative that doesn't require a recursive call is to forge a lookup array with one cycle (`foreach()`) and remove the unwanted element from the lookup, then iterate the balances array and swiftly merge related data set based on share company name values.

This assumes that the balances array should dictate which market values should be included in the result.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/WPeGC))

```
$lookup = [];
foreach ($market as $row) {
    $lookup[array_shift($row)] = $row;
}

var_export(
    array_map(
        fn($row) => $row + ($lookup[$row['company_code']] ?? []),
        $balances
    )
);
```